# redirecting URLs that have listing IDs attached

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm attempting to redirect the following page `traveltechjobs.com/display-job/42770/Entry-Level-Travel-Counselor--TEP-Extraordinary-Customer-Service.html`

to `http://hottraveljobs.com/display-job/42746/Dedicated-Account-Specialist--American-Express-Global-Business-Travel-(Florham-Park,-NJ).html`

and furthermore, to have the same happen for any item on the site with the /display-job/ after the .com to redirect to its mirror on hottraveljobs.

I attempted a few methods, mainly query redirect rules and a redirect match with no luck or 'listing ID not defined' as the result.

Is this possible, or will I have to manually create one for every page I wish to redirect?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that's what you want to do:

`.htaccess` for root folder:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^display-job/(\d+/) http://hottraveljobs.com/display-job/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change `[R=302]` for `[R=301]` when test work well.